# javascript: защита от обращения к несуществующим переменным

Tags: javascript, jquery, объекты, валидация

подскажите как правильнее было бы обрабатывать вот такие запросы:

```
$('.class1').on('click', function(e){

    if ((e.target != undefined) && (e.target.parentNode != undefined) && (e.target.parentNode.className != 'class2'))
        return;

    // тут остальной код
}
```

т.е. чтобы не делать такие вложенные проверки.

Как вариант, всегда можно написать свою функцию, которая принимает на вход строку, распарсивает её и дальше поэтапно проверяет объект

```
if ((myValidate(e, 'target.parentNode.className') == true) && (e.target.parentNode.className != 'class2'){...}
```

но может есть стандартные средства, хотя бы в том же jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конкретно Ваш код переписывается в такой

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.class1').on('click', 'div', function(e) {
    console.log($(this).text());
    if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('class2'))
      return;
    // тут остальной код
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1 class2">
  <div>Div1</div>
  <div>Div2</div>
  <div>Div3</div>
</div>
```

Немного расшифровки. В jQuery элемент у которого произошло событие, передается в обработчик как `this`. Это кроссбраузерно, в отличие от `e.target` и отсутствовать он не может.

`$(this).parent()` возвращает jQuery набор из родителя этого элемента. Если родителя нет, то набор пустой, но сам набор существует

`.hasClass('class2')` определяет, есть ли хоть у одного элемента в наборе класс `class2`. Соответственно, если набор пустой, то ответ `false`

---

Или можно вообще без проверок. Сразу прицепить обработчик на нужные элементы

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.class1').on('click', '.class2 > *', function(e) {
    // Цепляем обработчик на всех непосредственных потомков
    // элемента с классом class2
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
  
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.class1').append('<div class="class2"><div>Div0_1</div><div>Div0_2</div><div>Div0_3</div></div>');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div>Div2_1</div>
    <div>Div2_2</div>
    <div>Div2_3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class3">
    <div>Div3_1</div>
    <div>Div3_2</div>
    <div>Div3_3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button>Add</button>
```

Comment: натолкнул на мысль об уходе от обращения напрямую к данным, дело в том, что e.target позволяет определить, на что именно я нажал и родителя я получаю от этого элемента, а в приведённом коде родитель получается от элемента (например `body` на котором я ловлю нажатия). Ловить нажатия на одном элементе мне показалось целесообразнее, чем добавлять сотню обработчиков на дочерних элементах (вернее не просто дочерних, а дочерне дочерних :))

Comment: Сейчас сделал вот такой работающий код:

`$(e.target).parent().hasClass('class2')`

но опять же есть `e.target` который приходится еще и преобразовывать через `$`, но код стал удобнее и понятнее

Comment: @Zhihar так добавьте нужный селектор в `on` и получайте те элементы по которым кликнули (см обновленный ответ)

Comment: не совсем понял, скажем если у меня конструкция `<div class = 'main'><div class = 'parent'><div class = 'child'>` и я ловлю нажатия на `child` мне просто нужно указать нужный селектор `$('.main').on('click', '.child', function(e){})` (ловлю на основном, так как дочерние еще в процессе могут создаваться/удаляться и к ним явно привязываться нельзя, да и много их)

Comment: @Zhihar Именно так. Еще раз, обработчик создается один на `div.main`, а вызывается при клике на `.child`. И вызов обработчика не зависит от наличия или отсутствия элемента в момент создания самого обработчика (см второй обновленный ответ)

Answer (score 3):

Можно немного укоротить:

```
$('.class1').on('click', function(e){
  if (e && e.target && e.target.parentNode && e.target.parentNode.className != 'class2')
        return;
    // тут остальной код
}
```

Ждём [элвис-оператор](http://dev-city.me/2017/08/10/elvis-operator-v-javascript) с нетерпением